# How to yield the elements in an iterator within a new iterator?

Tags: python, json, iterator, yield

I need an iterator over all leaves in my JSON object. So I wrote this function

```
rec = {'a': {'b': [{'c': {'d': [{'e': 'x1','f': 'x2'}],'g': 'x3'}}],'h': 'x4','i': 'x5','j': [{'k': 'x6'}],'l': [{'m': {'n': 'x7'}}]}}

def yield_leaves(rec, lbl = ''):
  if isinstance(rec, dict):
    for key, value in rec.items():
        for to_yield in yield_leaves(value, key):
            yield to_yield
  if isinstance(rec, list):
    for value in rec:
        for to_yield in yield_leaves(value, lbl):
            yield to_yield
  if isinstance(rec, (int, str)):
    for entry in rec.split():
        yield entry, lbl

print(list(yield_leaves(rec)))
>>> [('x5', 'i'), ('x4', 'h'), ('x1', 'e'), ('x2', 'f'), ('x3', 'g'), ('x6', 'k'), ('x7', 'n')]
```

But I think some code is redundant. The following line

```
for to_yield in yield_leaves(value, key):
        yield to_yield
```

It iterates over an iterator and returns the values as part of an iterator.

Do you know a more efficient way to code this?

Comment: `yield from yield_leaves(value, key)` on Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last section

```
if isinstance(rec, (int, str)):
    for entry in rec.split():
        yield entry, lbl
```

is a bit strange. It will crash if `rec` is an `int`, since integers don't have a `.split` method. And none of your strings contain whitespace, so calling `.split` on them will just return a list containing a single item: the original string. I guess your real data may contain multi-word strings that you want to split, but if so, you really need to handle that separately from `int`s.

So assuming that you *don't* have multi-word values that you want to split, I've simplified your code a little. As you can see, I've only retained the `dict` and `list` tests, Since the data is decoded from JSON, any other `rec` types will be some sort of scalar: `int`, `str`, `bool`, or `None`, (unless you've created a custom decode), and we can handle all those scalar types identically.

```
rec = {
    'a': {
        'b': [
            {
                'c': {
                    'd': [{'e': 'x1', 'f': 'x2'}],
                    'g': 'x3'
                }
            }
        ],
        'h': 'x4',
        'i': 'x5',
        'j': [{'k': 'x6'}],
        'l': [{'m': {'n': 'x7'}}]
    }
}

def yield_leaves(rec, lbl=''):
    if isinstance(rec, dict):
        for key, value in rec.items():
            yield from yield_leaves(value, key)
    elif isinstance(rec, list):
        for value in rec:
            yield from yield_leaves(value, lbl)
    else:
        yield rec, lbl

print(list(yield_leaves(rec)))
```

**output**

```
[('x1', 'e'), ('x2', 'f'), ('x3', 'g'), ('x4', 'h'), ('x5', 'i'), ('x6', 'k'), ('x7', 'n')]
```

This code uses the Python 3 feature `yield from`; if you're not using Python 3, you should be. :)

Comment: Yes, ```yield from``` does what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: And you're right about calling split on integers. Bad copy-paste on my side

Answer (score 1):

Try to use yield from instead of for

```
yeild from yield_leaves(value, key)
```

P.S. If you are using python >3.3